# Jquery Messagebox call from server side code

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, messagebox

I am new to Jquery and trying to start learning the new tool. What I want to do is call a JQuery message box  from my gridViews Row Command function after the processing is done so I can notify the user the process has been complete.  I was trying to use this website as a referance
http://stuntsnippets.com/jquery-message-box/

But not sure how to call the function from the serverside. I have tried ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
Thank you,
Spafa9

Place this inside your script tags...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Determining if there is  a message to be shown if the message is not equal to empty string then the messagebox should appear.
    if(message != '') {
        message_box.show_message('Equipment Request:', message);
    }              
});

//JQuery to set up the messagebox.
var message_box = function () {
    var button = '<input type="button" onclick="message_box.close_message();" value="Ok" />';
    return {
        show_message: function (title, body) {
            if (jQuery('#message_box').html() === null) {
                var message = '<div id="message_box"><h1>' + title + '</h1>' + body + '<br/>' + button + '</div>';
                jQuery(document.body).append(message);
                jQuery(document.body).append('<div id="darkbg"></div>');
                jQuery('#darkbg').show();
                jQuery('#darkbg').css('height', jQuery('html, body').height());

                jQuery('#message_box').css('top', jQuery('html, body').scrollTop() + 150);
                jQuery('#message_box').show('slow');
            } else {
                var message = '<h1>' + title + '</h1>' + body + '<br/>' + button;
                jQuery('#darkbg').show();
                jQuery('#darkbg').css('height', jQuery('html, body').height());

                jQuery('#message_box').css('top', jQuery('html, body').scrollTop() + 150);
                jQuery('#message_box').show('slow');
                jQuery('#message_box').html(message);
            }
        },
        close_message: function () {
            jQuery('#message_box').hide('fast');
            jQuery('#darkbg').hide();
        }
    }
} ();
```

this goes in the CSS:

```
#darkbg {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;

    opacity: .5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
}
#message_box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    background: #fff;

    border: 4px solid #f0f0f0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;

    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
}
#message_box input[type=button] {
    float:left;
    margin-left: 145px;
}
```

In the if not is postback of the page you are using the message box on put this line of code:

```
ltlMessage.Text = "<script type=""text/javascript"">var message = """"; </script>"
```

Then in you row command under the function in which you would like to show the message box place this code.

```
ltlMessage.Text = "<script type=""text/javascript"">var message = ""Email has been sent.""; </script>"
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you've already tried?

Comment: I tried the following on of the guys I work with said that this should work. but just trying to do a simple alert doesnt come up. 
  $(document).ready(function () {

        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(ShowMessage);

        function ShowMessage() {
            //if(message != '') {
            //message_box.show_message('Hi!', 'Whatup?!');
            alert("I am here");
            //}              
        }
    });

Comment: I dont have enough characters to put in the rest of  it.  Basically the alert above I am trying to get to show up what I thought I would be able to do is set a literal to the message and check the literal to see if the message box should be displayed.

Comment: I can alway go back to calling javascript though code but wanted to try out JQuery and see if I could start to learn it.

Comment: @Spafa9: Update your original post and put your code in there.

Comment: I got it to work. I will up date the orginal post and see if I can get all the code in there to help someone else out that may have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modifed my post to include the working example. Hope this helps someone else out. One thing I forgot to note is on the page in which you would like the message box you will need a literal control to save off the message in my case it is called ltlmessage. 
Spafa9